# Write down a system of three equations in three unknowns with exactly three solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Write down a system of three equations in three unknowns with exactly three solutions.

I have absolutely no idea how to go about answering this question. Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This question has a lot of answers, so perhaps you have made ground on one of them?

Comment: I don't  even know how exactly to start.

Comment: Um... what don't you understand.  A system of three equations is clear.  three unknowns means three variables.  Call them x, y  and z.  Three solutions means that (x,y,z)=(a,b,c) and (x,y,z)= (d,e,f) and (x,y,z) = (g,h,i) are simultaneous solutions to the three equations.  My advice: make up the solutions first.  Come up with the exations second.

Comment: I doubt now about your question. tell please if you want to have exactly three solutions, $x,y,z$ or three solutions $(x_1,y_1,z_1), (x_2,y_2,z_2),(x_3,y_3,z_3)$.

Comment: Why don't you start with $2+1+3=6, 1+1-1=1, 7-1-6=0$. Then maybe turn these facts into a system of equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following system (assuming not every equation needs to have all of the three variables in it):
$$
(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=0 \\
y=0 \\
z=0
$$
This system has exactly three solutions: $(1,0,0),(2,0,0),(3,0,0)$.

Comment: Ooh wait I think I get it. So let's say they asked for 2 equations, two unknowns and 3 solutions then would the following be correct : x^3 +2x^2 -x=0 and y=0 ? With solutions (1,0),(-1,0) and (0,0). Or is that stil wrong

Comment: Your idea is correct, but your example is not. The three zeros of $x^3+2x^2-x$ are $x_1=0$, $x_2=-1-\sqrt{2}$ and $x_3=-1+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you should realize is that it cannot be a linear system of equations, because a linear system has either one unique solution, no solution, or infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If someone said "two equations, two solutions", I'd probably draw a circle and a line cutting through it.  Say, $x^2+y^2 = 1$ and $x=0$.  Or maybe a parabola with a line cutting it, say, $y=x^2$ and $y=1$.  So my advice is "think geometrically."

Comment: Three unknowns are needed.

Comment: You don't need three unknowns to think geometrically, which was, I think, B. Goddard's point. And besides, your third equation can always be $z = 0$, as in Janik's solution.